# Finding asymptotic upper and lower bound?

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity, lower-bound, upperbound

If we assume T(n) is constant for small n, how can we find the solution of this function?

```
T(n) = T(n−2) + 2logn
```

So far, I am unable to find a way to represent the whole function. Can you please help me? I really want to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming n is even, and that `T(1) = T(0) = 0`.

```
T(n)/2 = log(n) + log(n-2) + ... + log(2)
       = log((n/2)! * 2^n)
       = n log(2) + log((n/2)!)
       = n log(2) + n log(n) - n + O(log(n)) (Stirling's approximation)
```

So for `n` even, `T(n) = Theta(n log(n))`.

For `n` odd, you can note that `T(n-1) < T(n) < T(n+1)`, and get the same asymptotic bound.